# write in header section of custom installer page (without MUI)

Tags: nsis

I used this guide to create custom page in my installer:

[nsDialogs](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html)

and its working without a problem, this is the code:

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

XPStyle on

Var Dialog

Page custom nsDialogsPage nsDialogsPageLeave

Function nsDialogsPage

    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $Dialog

    ${If} $Dialog == error
        Abort
    ${EndIf}

    ...

    nsDialogs::Show

FunctionEnd

Function nsDialogsPageLeave

    ...

FunctionEnd

Section
SectionEnd
```

But the only thing missing is this part:

[image: example]

Could someone help me out and show how to add text there, but without this MUI, all the guides i tried to find are refering to the MUI way but i went with Pages instead so i would like to keep it that way, surely there is a way. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your screenshot looks like it is using the MUI layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot looks like MUI. Even when using MUI, custom pages still use `Page Custom ...`.

The MUI has a helper macro to set the text on the top for your custom pages:

```
!include MUI2.nsh

...

Function nsDialogsPage
!insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Blah" "Blah blah"
nsDialogs::...
...
FunctionEnd
```

This macro is documented in the MUI readme. It is not in the nsDialogs documentation because these labels are in the outer dialog, not in the inner page dialog.

In the unlikely event that you are not using MUI (but you are using the MUI dialog layout and `ChangeUI`) you can copy the `MUI_HEADER_TEXT` macro from the MUI(v1) source file or write your own custom macro based on the MUI source.